# Show Wordpress Child Pages as a menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a map site on the `footer.php` and I'm showing it using the `wp_nav_menu();` function, but I have another section inside the footer in which I want to show only the child from a parent page.

I was trying to use `wp_list_pages();` function but I didn't get the result I wanted.

How should I make this work?

Code of my footer.php:

```
      <div class="footer__catalog">
          <h5 class="footer__title">Catálogo</h5>
          <div class="footer__list">
              <?php
                    $args = array (
                        'title_li' => __('Catalogo')
                    );
               ?>
              <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And this is the result I want:

[image]

This is what I've got.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried also passing the `child_of` parameter? See the [Wordpress function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

Comment: This works! just one more question, I can't find how to delete the name of the parent, do you pass any parameter?, thank you!

Comment: You can pass a exclude parameter and an id